# How can I fix the variable declaration error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, variables, declaration

I am a programming newbie.I am trying to capture a udp ethernet packet,I use the following code:

```cs
using PcapDotNet.Packets.IpV4;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Transport;
using PcapDotNet.Packets;
//.. System usings


namespace FirstLesson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Packet wpacket;

            // wpacket = received packet

            UdpDatagram udp = null;
            TcpDatagram tcp = null;
            Datagram datagram = null;

            IpV4Datagram ip4 = wpacket.Ethernet.IpV4;
            if (ip4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Udp)
            {
                udp = ip4.Udp;
                datagram = udp.Payload;
            }
            if (ip4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Tcp)
            {
                tcp = ip4.Tcp;
                datagram = tcp.Payload;
            }
            if (null != datagram)
            {
                int payloadLength = datagram.Length;
                using (MemoryStream ms = datagram.ToMemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] rx_payload = new byte[payloadLength];
                    ms.Read(rx_payload, 0, payloadLength);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class Packet : IList<byte>, 
        ICollection<byte>, 
        IEnumerable<byte>, IEnumerable, 
        IEquatable<Packet> 
    { 
        private readonly byte[] _data; 
        private readonly DateTime _timestamp; 
        private readonly IDataLink _dataLink; 
        private bool? _isValid; 
        private EthernetDatagram _ethernet; 
        private IpV4Datagram _ipV4;
    }
```

And it gives the following error:

> Error  CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'wpacket'
> I don't know how to initialize the wpacket variable. I tried =null but it doesn't work properly.
> Please help me fix the code.
> Note: I have attached "Class Packet"
> `public sealed class Packet : IList<byte>, ICollection<byte>, IEnumerable<byte>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<Packet>`

Hope the code can work!

Comment: Well you're never assigning anything to `wpacket`... it's not clear why you're trying to refer to it. What do you expect `IpV4Datagram ip4 = wpacket.Ethernet.IpV4` to do? (I also see no `using` directives, so it's unclear which `Packet` type you're even trying to refer to...)

Comment: As Jon has said, when you initialise `ip4`, you are trying to access the `Ethernet` property of `wpacket`.  This will throw an error because there is no value that has been assigned to the `wpacket` variable. You need to populate /initialise the variable first before trying to access anything to do with Packet.

Comment: The comment `// wpacket = received packet` should be replaced by real code (not only to make it receive packets but also to get rid of this error). The minimal code would be: `wpacket = new Packet();` with any required constructor parameters or `wpacket = null;` or `wpacket = null!;` in a nullable context . This is not enough to receive packets but enough to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: Thank so much, this is Packet class:                                                                
public sealed class Packet : IList<byte>, ICollection<byte>, IEnumerable<byte>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<Packet>
{
    private readonly byte[] _data;

    private readonly DateTime _timestamp;

    private readonly IDataLink _dataLink;

    private bool? _isValid;

    private EthernetDatagram _ethernet;

    private IpV4Datagram _ipV4;                                                                                           I dont have ideal about the value type to initiate.

Comment: I use namespace PcapDotNet to capture ethernet packets
​

Comment: using PcapDotNet.Packets.IpV4;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Transport;
using PcapDotNet.Packets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: @linh mai It would be more beneficial to edit your question to include these rather than leaving them as a comment. I've put in an edit request to format this properly so it is easier to help if others see this.

Comment: @linh mai You need to initialise it with a Packet object based on the `Packet wpacket;` declaration. Olivier has pointed out the minimum declaration to at least solve the Compiler error, but if not initialised properly you may enounter a `NullReferenceException`.  Looking at the Pcap.Net repo, it has tests that show some ways of initialising a Packet object. You can read this [here in the PacketTests file in the repo](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/blob/master/PcapDotNet/src/PcapDotNet.Packets.Test/PacketTests.cs). I'll leave an answer with an example too as I can't fit it in a comment

Comment: Rather than leave an answer, there is [another file here](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/blob/master/PcapDotNet.DevelopersPack/src/CapturingThePacketsWithoutTheCallback/Program.cs) which shows a practical example of Capturing a packet. This will show you a way of initialising a packet.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the packet means actually building something into it. Equaling it to "null" would simply do not effect. What you have to do is to construct a new 'Packet' class.

Check this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Packet wpacket = new Packet(); 

    UdpDatagram udp = null;
    TcpDatagram tcp = null;
    Datagram datagram = null;

    IpV4Datagram ip4 = wpacket.Ethernet.IpV4;
    if (ip4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Udp)
    {
        udp = ip4.Udp;
        datagram = udp.Payload;
    }
    if (ip4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Tcp)
    {
        tcp = ip4.Tcp;
        datagram = tcp.Payload;
    }
    if (null != datagram)
    {
        int payloadLength = datagram.Length;
        using (MemoryStream ms = datagram.ToMemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] rx_payload = new byte[payloadLength];
            ms.Read(rx_payload, 0, payloadLength);
        }
    }
}
```

I also suggest you going over the documentation of the library, to get a better grasp on some other concepts related to it - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET

Good luck with the learnings!